# Google Colab DCGAN ml5.js error while using personal dataset: /bin/bash: .datatool.py: /usr/bin/env: bad interpreter: Permission denied

Tags: javascript, python, machine-learning, ml5.js

Original Github repo:

https://github.com/ml5js/training-dcgan

Hi all, I have zero background in Python, and do have some knowledge of JavaScript. Please bear with me.. hahah

I am trying to use ml5.js' DC-GAN training method on a very small set of data, comprised of my own personal images. I followed the instructions on the Github page - only this time, I did not import the repo - but downloaded it to my computer, placed my images manually by dragging my JPEGs in the `images` folder, then re-uploaded it to Google Drive, and imported the folder onto COLAB. I proceeded to follow the basic instructions, which worked until I reached the step where I had to convert to NumPy array, it generated this line;

[image]

Any help would be very much appreciated.

Notes:

- My dataset of images in total are about only 148 JPEGs, and are
  averaging at 1-2 MB. Haven't batch resized them into smaller images
  with the same aspect ratio and this is probably why some issues are
  happening but I highly doubt it as the code will resize the images
  anyway.

Comment: You say you have zero background in python but you are straight into neural networks? with Python??

Comment: fixed it already